# How to start watermark video when it appears?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

This is my scenario:

I want to add a watermark video in other video, but I want that the watermark starts when it appears.

Actually I'm able to display a watermark video and playing it from the beginning. 
If I try to add the watermark in a specific interval, it appears correctly in the period specified, but the watermark appears stopped because it starts when the main video is played.

This is the command that I'm using:

> ffmpeg -y -i big_buck_bunny.mp4 -i alpha.mov -filter_complex "[1:v]
>   fade=out:st=30:d=1:alpha=1 [ov]; [0:v][ov]
>   overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable=between(t\,3\,5) [v]" -map "[v]"
>   -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy out.mp4

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to super user.  This question needs a bit of clarification. Particularly the statements _"I want that the watermark starts when it appears"_ and _" it is stopped because it starts when the main video is played."_ Welcome and good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-itsoffset` just before the overlayed input with the same ammount of seconds you are using in the start of the filter (3 in your case)

This is maintaining the `fade out` filter you had, but that filter does not produce any visible results:

```
ffmpeg -y -i big_buck_bunny.mp4 -itsoffset 3 -i alpha.mov -filter_complex "[1:v] fade=out:st=30:d=1:alpha=1 [ov]; [0:v][ov] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable=between(t\,3\,5) [v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy out.mp4
```

This is with 3 inputs (2 overlays and a base) and without that other filter:

```
ffmpeg -y -i basevideo.mp4 -itsoffset 3 -i overlay1.mp4 -itsoffset 8 -i overlay2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable=between(t\,3\,5) [oa]; [oa][2:v] overlay=0:0:enable=between(t\,8\,10) [ob]"  -map "[ob]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

To keep adding overlayed videos:

- add `-itsoffset **X** -i newinput.mp4` after last input file.

  - **Order** of input files is important
  - `**X**` is the time the overlay video will *start* playing (this will not *show* the overlay, just start internally the play of the video). Adjust it as neccesary (probably matching the value of `**X**` in the next step)
- insert another `[**previous_output**][**Y**:v] overlay=0:0:enable=between(t\,**X**\,**Z**) [**new_output**]` after last block.

  - `**Y**` is the Yth input file, starting on 0 (in my example basevideo is 0, overlay1 is 1, overlay2 is 2, etc).
  - `**X**` is the time the overlay will *show* up in the output video.
  - `**Z**` is the time the overlay will *hide* in the output video.
  - Time is counted as for the start of the basevideo, not the lenght of the overlayed video, so do your calculations on duration: if the overlay video is 2 seconds long, `**Z**` will be `**X**` + 2.
- Adjust the `-map "[**XX**]` at the end of the command to match the `**new_output**`, or you will be writing to file the previous step!

**NOTE** audio is grabbed directly from *basevideo*. The audios from the other sources are ignored and will **not** play at all.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you a suggest how to configure the command if I have more than one overlay?

Comment: @stuzzo improved response